# Is there a way to download file without prompt in php/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**I am Working on laravel Project i have  excel file which i want to download without showing popup of where to save file.**

Answer (score 0):

Using `Storage::download()`, you can start the download instantly.

```
return Storage::download($path)
```

Related section [in Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#downloading-files).